# AppCompatSpinner throwing InflateException on only few devices

Tags: android, android-spinner, illegalargumentexception, app-themes

Two days i was stuck with IllegalArgument Exception(given the crash log below) while clicking on the custom AppCompatSpinner.
This issue is not happening in all devices, only few devices(Samsung, Oneplus) affected.
App themes are listed below for all the api version

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

v23 theme:

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

v21 theme :

```
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"
```

My crash log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #95: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class Button
        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class Button
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
```

Please give some insights to fix this issue. Found some solutions in stackoverflow & other sites but nothing helped me to fix the issue

Comment: upload your xml code

Comment: Are you placing all your drawable item in drawable(v24)

Comment: @Danish, No i have placed drawable items in drawable folder

Comment: Which version of Material theme you are using?

Comment: It may be related to the version of Material theme.

Comment: Ahh, okey. Currently i am using 1.2.1

Comment: Have you tried adding the theme in your manifest?

Comment: Yeah. Added my app theme to application

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Material UI elements, then

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` should be changed to `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">`.

As the error itself is saying, your app theme must be a child of `MaterialTheme` or any child of the same.

[How to build a material theme](https://material.io/resources/build-a-material-theme#how-to-using-glitch)

Comment: No, this solution is not working. I have already tried.
Note: This issue is happening only in few devices

Comment: @Madhu, The title of the question is completely different from the description, add the description related to the title

Comment: I have updated my title as my description is the issue which i am facing it

Comment: @Madhu add crashlog for `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: @Madhu, not the title, add the crash-log to the description, you can find crashlog in logcat

Comment: I have already provided the crash log in the description. It's an inflate exception

Comment: @Madhu Alright, can you please add the XML for the same layout.